# Tasks.await(task) shows Inappropriate blocking method call warning

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I'm trying to perform sign out via Google in my code:

```
suspend fun signOut(context: Context): Boolean = with(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        val signOutTask = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, 
        getGoogleSignInOptionsBuilder()).signOut()
        Tasks.await(signOutTask)
        true
    } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
        false
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        false
    }
}
```

The signOutTask is Task(Void) and I want it to return synchronously.
But in the following line:

```
Tasks.await(signOutTask)
```

It shows *Inappropriate blocking method call*
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Kotlin Coroutines with Google Play services' APIs, you should use the [`kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) which does the correct work to convert the `Task` API into `suspend` APIs without blocking your thread:

```
// In your dependencies block of your build.gradle
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.9"
```

This lets you write your code as:

```
suspend fun signOut(context: Context): Boolean = try {
    val signOutTask = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context,
         getGoogleSignInOptionsBuilder()).signOut()
    signOutTask.await()
    true
} catch (e: Exception) {
    false
}
```

Comment: You saved my day, spent 2 hours on this, wonder when Google will add this as part of their Tasks api.
Thank you very much!
One last question, should I always assume the if the task.await() pass - the task is successfull ?

Comment: In the case of `signOut()`, it is a `Task<Void>` means any await that successfully completes (i.e., doesn't throw an exception) is a success.